# HTTPS with nodejs and connect

Tags: node.js, https, node.js-connect

I'm currently using nodejs with connect as my HTTP server.
Is there anyway to activate HTTPS with connect?
I cannot find any documentation about it.

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_class_https_server.

Comment: Check out this blog post on Connect 2.0 http://tjholowaychuk.com/post/18418627138/connect-2-0

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of creating `http` server, use `https` server for connect :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var connect = require('connect')
  //, http = require('http'); Use https server instead
  , https = require('https');

var options = {
    key:    fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.key'),
    cert:   fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.crt'),
    ca:     fs.readFileSync('ssl/ca.crt')
};
var app = connect();
https.createServer(options,app).listen(3000);
```

See the documentation for `https` [here](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener) and `tls` server (https is a subclass of tls) [here](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener)

Answer (score 1):

From http://tjholowaychuk.com/post/18418627138/connect-2-0

> HTTP and HTTPS
>
> Previously connect.Server inherited from Node’s core net.Server, this
>   made it difficult to provide both HTTP and HTTPS for your application.
>   The result of connect() (formerly connect.createServer()) is now
>   simply a JavaScript Function. This means that you may omit the call to
>   app.listen(), and simply pass app to a Node net.Server as shown here:
>
> ```
> var connect = require('connect')
>   , http = require('http')
>   , https = require('https');
>
> var app = connect()
>   .use(connect.logger('dev'))
>   .use(connect.static('public'))
>   .use(function(req, res){
>     res.end('hello world\n');
>   })
>
> http.createServer(app).listen(80);
> https.createServer(tlsOptions, app).listen(443);
> ```

The same is true for express 3.0 since it inherits connect 2.0